# Regex named groups and conditional logic

Tags: python, regex

Consider the following string (edit: this is not a parsing HTML with regexs questions. Rather just an exercise with named groups):

```
s = """<T1>
        <A1>
        lorem ipsum
        </A1>
      </T1>"""
```

Is it possible to use `re.sub` and named groups to transform the string into this result?

```
<T1>
  <test number="1">
  lorem ipsum
  </test>
</T1>
```

Right now I have the following code:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("(<(?P<end>\/*)A(?P<number>\d+)>)")
print regex.sub('<\g<end>test number="\g<number>">', s)
```

which gives the following result

```
<T1>
  <test number="1">
  lorem ipsum
  </test number="1">
</T1>
```

Can an `|` operator be used like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903562/python-regular-expressions-named-groups-and-logical-or-operator)?

Comment: never use regex for parsing html or xml , instead use proper modules that is for this tasl like `lxml` or ...

Comment: I understand (normally I would always use `lmxl`). This is just an exercise for my understanding of `re`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to match the whole tag. Not only the opening and closing tags but catch also it's contents.

REgex:

```
(<(?P<end>\/*)(A)(?P<number>\d+)>)(.*?)</\3\4>
```

REplacement string:

```
<test number="\g<number>">\5</test>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yD2cY0/1)

```
>>> s = """<T1>
        <A1>
        lorem ipsum
        </A1>
      </T1>"""
>>> import re
>>> print(re.sub(r'(?s)(<(?P<end>\/*)(A)(?P<number>\d+)>)(.*?)</\3\4>', r'<test number="\g<number>">\5</test>', s))
<T1>
        <test number="1">
        lorem ipsum
        </test>
      </T1>
```

`(?s)` called DOTALL modifier which matches makes dot in your regex to match even newline characters also.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I didn't think about matching against everything and then just including  `</test>` in the replacement string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
x="""<T1>
    <A1>
    lorem ipsum
    </A1>
  </T1>"""

def repl(obj):

    if obj.group(1):
        return '/test'
    else:
        return 'test number="'+obj.group(2)+'"'

print re.sub(r"(\/*)A(\d+)",repl,x)
```

You can tyr the replacement function provided by `re.sub`.

Comment: @Jeff you re welcome.You can use this technique to attain difficult substitutes based on captures.

Answer (score 1):

You can use look-around to match string between `<T1>` and `</T1>` :

```
>>> p = re.compile(ur'(?<=<T1>)[^<]+?(.+)(?=</T1>)', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
>>> s2='\n  <test number="1">\n  lorem ipsum\n  </test>\n'
>>> print p.sub(s2,s,re.MULTILINE)
<T1>
  <test number="1">
  lorem ipsum
  </test>
</T1>
```

you need to use following [Contents](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents) :

> **re.IGNORECASE**
>   Perform case-insensitive matching; expressions like [A-Z] will match lowercase letters, too. This is not affected by the current locale.
>
> **re.MULTILINE**
>   When specified, the pattern character '^' matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following each newline); and the pattern character '$' matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each newline). By default, '^' matches only at the beginning of the string, and '$' only at the end of the string and immediately before the newline (if any) at the end of the string.
>
> **re.DOTALL**
>   Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.

Comment: @Jeff you're welcome , note that using the following contents could be very helpful in such cases